# Как вернуть Id определенного объекта с определенным статусом?

Tags: python, requests

**Вот пример респонса:**

```
[
  {
    "type": 2,
    "id": "32d885cd-1e61-427a-b5d7-3025fe078ff2",
    "campaignId": 24,
    "status": 1,
    "endDate": "2021-08-30T17:21:19.031844",
    "name": "SecondName"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "id": "bdde6b45-fba1-4290-ac6a-ff3158967439",
    "campaignId": 25,
    "status": 1,
    "endDate": "2021-08-31T00:21:19.123064",
    "name": "TestName"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "id": "1d687c58-ed71-4c34-a7f9-8924a4a307f2",
    "campaignId": 25,
    "status": 2,
    "endDate": "2021-08-31T00:21:21.123064",
    "name": "3-rdName"
  }
]
```

Вот пример моего кода, я его обернул в Try->Except, так как допустимо пустой респонс.

```
   req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   assert_that(req.status_code).is_equal_to(200)
   res = req.json()
   try:
      res[0]['id']
      return res[0]['id']
   except IndexError:
       print("There are the empty response")
```

Данный код возвращает первый **"id": "32d885cd-1e61-427a-b5d7-3025fe078ff2"**.
Как задать правильно условие, чтоб возвращалось **Id** объекта с определенным **status**?
Должно выглядеть примерно следующим образом, но не уверен:

```
active_bonus = req.json()
pending_bonus = req.json()
try:
   if active_bonus['status'] == 1:
       return active_bonus['id']
   elif pending_bonus['status'] == 2:
       return pending_bonus['id']
except IndexError:
    print("There are the empty response")
```

Данный код естественно не работает!

Answer (score 0):

Четыре раза прочел -так и не понял, что вам надо сделать.
Но вот так:

```
for active_bonus in res:
    if active_bonus['status']==1:
        print (active_bonus['id'])
```

вы получаете "*Id объекта с определенным status*"

Comment: Согласен, трудновато выложил описание своей проблемы. Данный код возвращает первый **Id** со статусом 1. 
А не подскажете, как вернуть ИД со статусом 1 и ИД со статусом 2 в соответствующих переменных?

Comment: if active_bonus['status']==1 or active_bonus['status']==2:  За одно вам, как новичку, подсказываю: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: решил не изобретать велосипед и создал две функции - одно возвращает ИД с одним статусом, а вторая ИД с другим.

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял, что вы хотите, но могу предложить такой вариант:

```
active_bonus = req.json()
pending_bonus = req.json()
try:
   for i in range(len(active_bonus)):
       if active_bonus[i]['status'] == 1:
           return active_bonus[i]['id']
       if pending_bonus[i]['status'] == 2:
            return pending_bonus[i]['id']
except IndexError:
    print("There are the empty response")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: @Daniel, Спасибо за предложенный вариант решения, но данный код возвращает только первый Id со статусом 1. **ELIF** для  pending_bonus не работает( тоесть, Id со статусом 2 не выводится.

Comment: я написал, исходя из вашего шаблона. Замените elif на if